# How can I define a function parameter to be a function or null?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
task = (
         data: string,
         taskCallback: (data: any) => any
       ) => {     
};
```

How can I make this even more generic so that successCallback could be a function that takes and returns anything or it could be an argument that's not even supplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do understand your request properly, the defintion should be with a **`Function`** :

```
var task = (
        data: string,
        //taskCallback: (data: any) => any,
        taskCallback: Function  // here we go, requiring the function
        ) => { ...};
```

And then we can have these:

```
 var callback1 = () => { }
 var callback2 = (data: any) => { }
 var callback3 = () => { return 1; }
```

And this will compile:

```
 task("data", callback1);
 task("data", callback2);
 task("data", callback3);
 task("data", null);
```

but this not:

```
 task("data", 1); // 1 is number not a function
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way I tried this in Visual Studio 2013. It accepts it okay but unlike string, number when I write Function it does not appear in blue like a keyword.  Have you noticed the same thing?

Comment: Yes!!! Yess exactly the same surprise, sir... I do not know why... but that's still just some sugar for us. Important is that Function in this case is what we need. Does it help?

Comment: Its because `Function` isn't a keyword. (`function` is). `Function` is more akin to `String` or `Number` (not keywords but interfaces, and aren't highlighted either)

Comment: @RadimKöhler you don't need to use `Function`

Answer (score 0):

What you have **already** does what you need

```
var task = (
         data: string,
         taskCallback: (data: any) => any
       ) => {     
};
```

Examples from *Radim*'s answer :

```
 var callback1 = () => { }
 var callback2 = (data: any) => { }
 var callback3 = () => { return 1; }

task("data", callback1);
task("data", callback2);
task("data", callback3);
task("data", null);

task("data", 1); // 1 is number not a function
```

Reason: It is okay for a callback function to take *less* than the number of arguments expected. More : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type%20Compatibility#comparing-two-functions

Comment: I see your point. ID Do like Typescript ;) but on the other hand, the function passed can have more params in my solution not in yours `var callback4 = (data: any, bar: number) => {}` - this cannot be used in your solution

Comment: Agreed. "takes anything" I took it as takes 1 argument of anything. You took it as "any number of arguments of anything" The number wasn't specified ;)

Comment: @Radim Köhler But in that scenario you might as well go with ...args: any[]